# Having problems access jQuery from a external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here's how I formatted jQuery to load in my HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my JavaScript file:

```
var i = 0;
var a = 0;
var Backspacing = false;
var Paragraph = false;

var textArray = [
     "Welcome!",
     "My name is Jay",
     "I'm creative",
     "I'm a problem solver",
     "And best of all...",
     "I love learning new things"
 ];
 var speedForward = 100;
 var speedWait = 1000;
 var speedBetweenLines = 1000;
 var speedBackspace = 25;

function typeWriter(id, ar){
     var element = $("#" + id);// I would get an error here



}
```

The problem is when I'm trying to use "$" or a function such as setTimeout in my external JavaScript file , I keep getting an error saying that it is not defined. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Code in `script.js` will definitely have access to `$` given the above. There must be something else going on that you haven't shown us.

Comment: How is `typeWriter` called?

Comment: try adding this add the end of the body. If this fires, Jquery Works and you have done something wrong in ur js file. `<script>$(() =>alert('jquery works') )</script>`

Comment: [Works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-61700977-g65tn).

Comment: Try switching a browser or turn off, for test, your antivirus. Something is wrong on your pc.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem by using visual studio code instead of brackets.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure in your **script.js** everything should be inside below code block, and instead of **$** try using **jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  // you code should be in this block     

});
```